# Antisymmetric functions in $L^2([-1,1])$ and their expression as determinants

Tags: real-analysis, calculus-of-variations

Given functions $f,g \in L^2([-1,1]),$ we can construct antisymmetric functions in $L^2([-1,1]\times [-1,1])$ by defining:
$$F(x,y) = f(x)g(y)-f(y)g(x),$$ which is the antisymmerization of $f(x)g(y),$ or, equivalently,the determinant
$$F(x,y) = \begin{vmatrix}
f(x) & f(y)   \\  
g(x) & g(y)  \notag
\end{vmatrix}. $$

In general, I call "determinant" to an antisymmetric function $F \in L^2([-1,1],[-1,1])$ that can be expressed as above for certain $f,g \in L^2([-1,1]).$

Now, for a generic antisymmetric $ F \in  L^2([-1,1]\times [-1,1])$, $F(x,y) = -F(y,x)$, what are the $f,g \in L^2([-1,1])$ such that $f(x)g(y)-f(y)g(x)$ is closest to $F$ in the $L^2$ norm.
For example, consider the determinants:
$$x y^2 - y x^2$$
and
$$\sin(x) e^y - \sin(y) e^x,$$
and combine them linearly:
$$\alpha \left( x y^2 - y x^2 \right)   + \beta \left( \sin(x) e^y - \sin(y) e^x \right)$$

It is intuitive that this combination cannot be expressed as a determinant for arbitrary $\alpha,\beta,$ but I cannot prove it. And how to find the closest determinant?